# My state variable is not updating - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox-gl-js, chakra-ui

```js
export default function Home() {
    const [tooltip, setTooltip] = useState(false);

    return (
        <DeckGL
            initialViewState={viewport}
            controller={true}
            ContextProvider={_MapContext.Provider}
            width="100vw"
            height="100vh"
        >
            <StaticMap
                mapStyle={"mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"}
                mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
            />
            <Marker
                latitude={currentLocation.lat}
                longitude={currentLocation.long}
            >
                <Flex
                    onMouseEnter={() => setTooltip(true)}
                    onMouseLeave={() => setTooltip(false)}
                >
                    {tooltip ? <Box2 /> : <Box1 />}
                </Flex>
            </Marker>
            )}
        </DeckGL>
    );
}
```

I know there are a lot of answers regarding this question but I don't seem to make it work.

So I have a marker on my mapbox and I have a state variable "tooltip". If the mouse hovers on the marker and it sets it to true and when it leaves sets it to false.

If I replace "setTooltip(true)}" with console.log it works flawlessly, so I don't know why the state is not changing.

I want to show one box if it's true () and another if it's false ().

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have any `console.log` in your code. And if you mean that you set the state and immediately `console.log` it on the next line, that won't work because state changes asynchronous. Print state in the main body of the function to see the latest value

Comment: No, I meant if I replace "setTooltip(true)}" with console.log it works flawlessly, so the state is changing.

Comment: Consider using css instead of JavaScript? It may help simplify things

Comment: If you initialize tooltip as true, will Box2 be displayed?

Comment: How are you verifying/validating that state isn't updating? Agreed, using a pure CSS version trumps any JS solution, 100% of the time.

Comment: Yes, if I initialize tooltip as true, Box2 is displayed instead

Comment: @linchong Maybe the variable is not updating at all..

Comment: @Borbat it might be that the component `Flex` does not support those props. https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-poincare-qtvct is a [mcve] which shows the approach works.

Comment: You can try it yourself by replacing all these custom components with `div`